# segfaulting with fgets, even though fopen doesn't return NULL in C

Tags: c

I've looked all over and made sure there were no warnings, but my code to replace text with digits keeps returning segfault. Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(argv[1] , "r");
    char *line = malloc(1024);
    if(file != NULL)
    {
        while(fgets(line , sizeof(line) , file))
        {
//things
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR: %s NOT AVAILABLE" , argv[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you know `malloc` could also return `NULL` and there exists `free`?

Comment: please post the input file, and how are you invoking the program, and what are things?

Comment: BTW, `sizeof(line)` is probably 4 or 8 (and is not the `malloc`-ed size, it is the size of the pointer, not the memory zone)

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: The code you posted compiles without warning or error under gcc, and the result runs for me without segfaulting when given the name of its own source file as the first argument, or when given the name of a nonexistant file as its first argument.  As others have pointed out, your usage of `sizeof` is incorrect, but that will not be the cause of your segfault because it is sure to yield a value that is less than the number of bytes `malloc()`ed for `line`.

Comment: your problem should be elsewhere - you might be misusing size of line

Comment: I suspect the cause of the segfault is somewhere in `//things`... Even if it's a not-immediately-fatal out of bounds access that corrupts your heap and causes `malloc()` or `fgets()` to choke some time later...

Comment: Problem is certainly in `//things`.  Suggest posting more of `//things`.

Comment: Yes please I told you before, and repeat now, you can't be sure that the problem is not in `//things` so post it, it has to be there.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
char *line = malloc(1024);
```

with:

```
char line[1024] = {0};
```

or:

```
char line[1024];
```

if you don't want to clear out the line buffer.

Otherwise, you end up with two problems.

First:

```
sizeof(line)
```

returns the size of the pointer (4 or 8 bytes). That's not what you want.

Second: You have a memory leak because you don't `free` the `line` pointer at the end.

You can use `malloc` if you want, but you want to write clean(er) code to do this. You might do something like:

```
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024

/* ... */

char *line = NULL;
line = malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
if (!line) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not allocate space for line buffer!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

FILE *file = NULL;

/* Avoid undefined behavior by making sure filename argument holds a value */

if (argv[1])
    file = fopen(argv[1] , "r");

if (file != NULL) { /* You could also do "if (file) { ... }" */
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file)) {
        /* ... */
    }
}

free(line);
line = NULL;
```

As a habit, explicitly initialize pointers to `NULL`, and check that they actually hold a value before using them. Welcome to C!

Comment: Correct on all counts, but none of that explains the segfault that is the subject of the question.